# Exe file fails to run in Windows XP SP3 32 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-xp-sp3

I don't know why. It may be run in all systems I've already tested, including Windows XP/7 32/64 bit. It's a console application generated by Visual Studio 2010. I put a simple printf as the first statement in main function. But nothing is printed on screen. It seems that the exe file can't be executed. It's dependent to some other dll's and the dll's are included in the same folder as the exe file. If they can't be located, a message box must appear to warn about it, though, i think, not? The folder is completely copied from a system which this exe file can be run on. Only this exe file can't be run. I've examined another one which is also dependent to some dll's and it may be run without any problem.
Any clue?

Comment: can u just check the Event Viewer u can come to know actually wats the prblm is.!!

Comment: Please add details of the dependencies that are failing (if you are not sure tools file Process Monitor will tell you).

Comment: @RaviKanth: nothing is logged in event log.

Comment: @Richard: thx. go to use Process Monitor and see what will happen

Comment: ok. now i examined it by ProcessMonitor. first, i found mfc100d.dll should be available. why system doesn't prompt for this?! before this, the exe file was statically linked with mfc. but i changed it to see what happen. after copying mfc100d.dll to system32, it seems that there's no error. but my prog exists.
i include the log export in two formats:
http://cdn.persiangig.com/download/urDLXoV5NR/log.7z/dl

Comment: There are merge modules to deploy the MFC runtime (more than just copying one file is required). No idea why you're not getting a prompt (could be console subsystem difference). (Why using MFC in a console app is another question for another time.)

Comment: forgot to say that my program is IsoServer.exe in the log. seems not to have any problem. just exits! we use MFC for classes like CSocket etc. It's a server which gets packets and needs MFC anyway.
going to run redistributables.

Comment: The processor is Pentium 4. Maybe instructions for newer processors are generated and this is the cause? If so, how can I make VS 2010 generate compatible instructions?